# Rails Ajax Request Controller Action not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've been battling this for a while now and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I'm just trying to send a simple ajax request to get details for a modal.

Ajax Call:

```
$('.invite-button').on('click', function() {
  var path = $(this).data('path');
  $.get(path).success( function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

Controller Action:

```
def invite_details
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @campaigns = current_user.campaigns
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {}
    end
end
```

invite_details.js.erb :

```
$('.invite-modal').html("<%= j render partial: 'users/invite', locals: {campaigns: @campaigns} %>")
```

_invite.html.erb :

```
<h1> Hello! </h1>
<ul>
  <% campaigns.each do |campaign| %>
    <li><%= campaign.title %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Server Logs:

```
Started GET "/users/8/invite_details" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-30 10:06:43 -0400
Processing by UsersController#invite_details as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"8"}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Transaction Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "transactions".* FROM "transactions"  WHERE "transactions"."brand_id" = 1
  Rendered users/invite_details.js.erb (0.1ms)
  SQL (2.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_activity_at" = '2014-09-30 14:06:43.484838' WHERE "users"."id" = 1
Completed 200 OK in 14ms (Views: 5.4ms | ActiveRecord: 3.7ms)
```

Everything in the logs looks fine except that it's not actually querying the database for @user or @campaigns, and they're empty in the layouts. I've also tried putting a binding.pry into the controller action and it doesn't get run. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it's getting the user from the db. Any reason you're using current_user to get the campaigns instead of the @user variable?

Comment: Yea they're actually different users.  @user is grabbing the person that the 'current_user' is inviting.

Comment: And the server is loading a user with the 'id' of 1, but the parameters have an 'id' of 8. I'm really confused about this one.

Comment: If you do console.log the output of whatever path is, does it match the route you expect?

Comment: Yup it does. Based on the server logs, everything is working except the code in the controller action doesn't seem to be running. I get 'Hello!' rendered in the modal (from _invite.html.erb), but that's it.

Comment: Two quick questions: (1) how does your JavaScript code get called? (2) have you tried testing the controller action/method via the browser (i.e., the users/8/invite_details). I realize you might have to add a route and html response but it could be worth a try ... or check out the RailsPanel Chrome extension and the better_errors gem; they've saved me some serious headaches when dealing with async calls, etc.

Comment: (1) On the click of a button that triggers the modal, the ajax request gets sent to grab the information to populate it. (2) Great suggestion. I just tried it and rendered out the variables and no dice.  I threw a breakpoint in and they were both nil. However, the params are still available and I was able to duplicate the controller action code in the layout and it worked perfectly. For some reason the controller action just isn't doing anything. I'll take a look at the extension and gem to see if they help. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Is this s typo just here or on the actual code too. The code within `li` tags in `_invite.html.erb` is not wrapped properly. It needs to be this:

```
<h1> Hello! </h1>
<ul>
  <% campaigns.each do |campaign| %>
    <li><%= campaign.title %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```